# db2 alter column statement from char to varchar

Tags: db2

Does it possible using some db2 trick to alter a column from type char to type varchar trimming the white space on the right?

I know that is possible to alter the column type from char to varchar (to extends its size)
but db2 leaves the left white space on the right, so I need  to issue an update statement after the alter table statement to trim the white space on the right.

But we have table also with 400 million of records and the update statement has an important cost in terms of time.

I ask this question also after I read the db2 documentation of alter table statement: seems that does exists nothing that allows me to change the type and trim right the values at the same time.

Comment: The time it takes is irrelevant. If it could be done in a single operation it would also take a long time. It possibly would even lock the table longer.

Comment: Use a view over the table...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to do what you ask for. Have you considered export and load replace?

Comment: Wouldn't that take a lot longer than the update? And the table would be unavailable in the interim.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can do the UPDATE after the ALTER. You have the spaces now.  In a sense, you are simply making a small improvement to the data. It may take a while, but how much does it matter if that process chugs away for a while in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Doing an export+load would have a significant downtime for the table.

If you use the alter to varchar and update approach you could minimize the log and lock amount by performing the update within a compound sql or stored procedure which commits after X rows updated.

This would still run quite long but locks won't be held that long.